# StreamInsight Server Clustering

Tags: scaling, streaminsight

I am Microsoft BI developer and I am in evaluation process of tool for complex event processing for one of my client.
I came across lot of tools from various background like WSo2, Jboss + drools, Nesper and Microsoft StreamInsight and 
As I am from Microsoft SQL Server background I prefer the Microsoft tools only.
There is one concern before we finalize this tool is that limit of Streaminsight event processing capacity for per second.
It is 5000 per seconds for Standard version but we are looking for current 15000-20000 (more in coming years) events per
seconds. So my question is can we cluster multiple Streamlight server to add capacity to handle events per seconds and
Required if yes can tell me the location to get this knowledge "how to cluster multiple Streaminsight server".

Answer (score 1):

Answered on the StreamInsight MSDN Forum: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/bbb95b51-2fd8-443e-b71d-c9952fdb6bdc/how-to-cluster-multiple-streminsight-server?forum=streaminsight.

Sorry ... you won't get another answer here. Your best way to scale is to use the Premium edition; you'll be able to easily exceed the 15000-20000 events/second with Premium. On a laptop, no less.